# Should we delete duplicate questions

Tags: discussion

Questions like [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16051/in-which-pase-of-birth-cycle-jivatman-enters-the-body) should be deleted after they are tagged duplicate? please justify your answer.

Comment: Duplicate questions make a good inter linked database & it makes easier for other user's to search. The question should not be deleted. If a Qn is downvoted & doesn't have any answer then it may get deleted automatically by SE bot.

Comment: @iammilind I agree with good interlinked database, it increases the probability of finding exact search results as we have multiple links pointing towards same question page. But in my case the question may be unnecessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [Help Center](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates):

> The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place. This does not mean that every duplicate will immediately be closed; [we love (some) dupes](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/).

From [How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841/260388):

> ### Should duplicates be deleted?
>
> In general, no: most duplicates stay around. Having multiple copies of the same question with different wording is useful as search fodder, because people looking for an answer may use different wording too.
>
> Duplicates that are word-for-word copies or that are so poorly written that they are not useful may be deleted by users with sufficient privilege.

Visit the blog dedicated to [Handling Duplicate Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/handling-duplicate-questions/)

Following meta posts may also useful:

- [**Duplicate question etiquette: to delete or not to delete?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230/260388) - your/this case
- [Do not delete good duplicates!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32311/260388)

---

You should not delete answer if

- Your wording is different and may be useful to others
- Your question have good answer(s)

But in this case, question doesn't have any good answer and wording is similar. So, you ***may*** delete your question thought it is up to you.

Comment: Does sometime system also delete duplicate questions?

Comment: @YDS check "By system" section at [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/260388)